# What sports would a horse play?

Tags: society, culture, sports

So, you're a sapient, fun loving, and incredibly bored horse and so are your millions of culturally similar hoofed amigos. What sports could sate your equine needs?

To specify this is aside from the obvious Equestrian sports already enjoyed ,or more likely not, by real world horses and by no means has to be a human sport, and alongside this, this isn't just a question of possibility but if it would be enjoyable. Eg; Would a horse enjoy bowling? Paragliding? Bobsled?

Comment: You are asking for a potentially endless list. The sort of questions not really in our scope.

Comment: Minecraft. Everybody wants to play Minecraft.

Comment: Hmm. Do you think horses would enjoy horseplay? Or, can horseplay be made a competitive sport?

Comment: I like the idea of the question, but as an open-ended list request, I'm gonna have to VTC. That said, as youtube will confirm, horses _really_ like playing with giant inflatable balls.

Comment: Do a search on "toys for horses".

Answer (score 1):

One, Two Three, Four, I declare a neck war!  -- two horses place their heads side by side and at the start of the contest, try to force their opponents head down to their chest.

Bite the Tail of the Donkey -- many horse chase after a single 'donkey' the first one to nip some hairs of the donkey's tail wins

Tic-Tac-Dung -- self-explanatory

Break-a-leg -- daring young males race through fields of prairie dogs -- or similar species.  The win has the fastest time, the losers break their legs and have to be put down.

Water polo -- obviously

Buck-Buck -- big, but stupid horses, take turns bucking each other in the head with their hind hooves.  The loser loses consciousness first.

Answer (score 0):

- Football / Headball
- Catch
- Jump far
- Running in circles
- Twister :)

Answer (score 0):

Grazing. We don't think of it as a sport, but I am sure your fun-loving sapient equines would turn it into one, or several.

There would be speed contests for finding a particular plant. There would be social clubs that go out to graze together in interesting areas. There would be special parks, with high admission fees, planted with gourmet grasses and weeds. Horse chefs would get rated on the interesting combinations of grasses in their parks.